# JSON serialize unexpected token when passed to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I'm attempting to take a basic serializable object that's held within a seriazable dictionary and pass it to a javascript function that will generate a modal with that information. The object has a few string variables, nothing complicated.

Here's the object I'm passing in:

```
[Serializable]
public class Details
{
    public Details() {}

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I set the strings to their appropriate values, and then attempt to create a link that calls a javascript modal (the ID is calling the appropriate:

```
protected string WriteDetailsLink(object ID)
{
    string results = "";

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    results += "showDetailsModal(" + jss.Serialize(dictionaryList[ID.ToString()]) + "); return false;";

    return results;
}
```

And the html link itself on the aspx page:

```
<a id='detailsDialog' onclick="<%# WriteDetailsLink( Eval( "ID" )) %>">Details</a>
```

And the javascript function for the modal, currently displaying nothing:

```
function showDetailsModal(Details) {



    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {

        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```

Everything works fine, the ID gets passed along and when I inspect the link after running it looks like this:

```
<a id='detailsDialog' onclick="showDetailsModal({"ID":"40662463","Name":"72485-3"}); return false;">Details</a>
```

And it looks to be the same format as code elsewhere in our project, but I keep getting a

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

error. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. If I pass just a string to the modal function, it works. I really don't want to have to send a bunch of clumsy strings and have to parse through them manually.

---

UPDATE:

Yup, it was the quotes around the link that was causing the issue. But now I'm encountering a new problem:

I've got a div setup for the modal and I'm attempting to parse out the name to insert into it, here's the new function (notice Name is now BatchName):

```
function showBatchDetailsModal(groupDetails) {

    var tmpData = jQuery.parseJSON(groupDetails);

    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {
            $('#detailsName').text(tmpData.BatchName);
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```

I'm getting

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o " in jquery.min.js

Comment: Looks like the quotes are messed up to me !

Answer (score 2):

Change your `onclick` to use single quotes to wrap the function call:

```
onclick='<%# WriteDetailsLink( Eval( "ID" )) %>'
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you very much! But I've since run into a new issue, I've updated my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be he following

```
function showBatchDetailsModal(groupDetails) {

    var tmpData = groupDetails; // jQuery.parseJSON(groupDetails);
    //Don't need to parse it into json. as its already parsed.

    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {
            $('#detailsName').val(tmpData.BatchName); //<--- .text(...) is changed to .val(...)
            //If val(...) doesn't work use .text(...)
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```